# Сохранение в jquery?

Tags: jquery

Как сделать так, чтобы когда я захожу на страницу и нажимаю на `checkbox` (ставлю флаг), то при перезагрузке страницы он бы остался? Как бы сохранилась информация, что этот `checkbox` с флагом?

Comment: Зделано! Извините, я тут новинкий :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так — http://jsfiddle.net/QPrNb/

```
jQuery(function ($){
  $.each(localStorage, function (i){
        key = localStorage.key(i);
        if( key.indexOf('cbx.') === 0 ){
            var checked = localStorage.getItem(key) == "true";
            $('input[name="'+key.substr(4)+'"]').prop('checked', checked);
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function (){
        localStorage.setItem('cbx.'+this.name, this.checked+'');
    });
});
```

P.S. Для localSotrage поищите polyfill (если нужна поддержка старых браузеров).

Comment: Огромное Спасибо!